# Nginx split the URI into variables to use on proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxy, regex, nginx-reverse-proxy, uri

I'm tring to get the URI parts to then pass it to the proxy_pass url. But I don't know about regex to do this.

I need to get the first and last URI into a variables to pass it on the proxy_pass like this:

```
https://example.com/user/port
```

to

```
proxy_pass http://user.example.com:$port
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

*Nginx config Example:*

```
location ~ ^/(\w+)/(\d+)$ {
  set $user $1;
  set $port $2;
  proxy_pass http://${user}.example.com:$port;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did like this: location ~ ^/(.*)/(.*)$ { proxy_pass http://$1.example.com:$2/; } is correct also?